# How to list all materialized view tables in Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, datastax

How to list all

> materialized view tables

in Cassandra CQL

> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.7.1158 | DSE 5.0.0 | CQL spec 3.4.0 |
>   Native protocol v4]

Answer (score 18):

Probably the easiest way is from the views schema table with:

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.views;
```

Comment: It shows all keyspace views, how can we view just in one keyspace?

Comment: SELECT view_name FROM system_schema.views where keyspace_name='myKeyspace';